# Express server that creates maximum of 2 child/worker processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fork, child-process

I'm experimenting with node and it's child_process module.
My goal is to create server which will run on maximum of 3 processes (1 main and optionally 2 children).
I'm aware that code below may be incorrect, but it displays interesting results.

```
const app = require ("express")();
const {fork} = require("child_process")

const maxChildrenRuning = 2
let childrenRunning = 0

app.get("/isprime", (req, res) => {

  if(childrenRunning+1 <= maxChildrenRuning) {
    childrenRunning+=1;
    console.log(childrenRunning)
    const childProcess = fork('./isprime.js');
    childProcess.send({"number": parseInt(req.query.number)})
    childProcess.on("message", message => {
      console.log(message)
      res.send(message)
      childrenRunning-=1;
    })
  }
})


function isPrime(number) {
...
}

app.listen(8000, ()=>console.log("Listening on 8000") )
```

I'm launching 3 requests with 5*10^9'ish numbers.
After 30 seconds I receive 2 responses with correct results.
CPU stops doing hard work and goes idle
Surprisingly after next 1 minute 30 seconds 1 thread starts to proceed, still pending, 3rd request and finishes after next 30 seconds with correct answer. Console log displayed below:

```
> node index.js

Listening on 8000
1
2
{ number: 5000000029, isPrime: true, time: 32471 }
{ number: 5000000039, isPrime: true, time: 32557 }
1
{ number: 5000000063, isPrime: true, time: 32251 }
```

Either express listens and checks pending requests once for a while or my browser sends actual requests every x time while pending. Can anybody explain what is happening here and why? How can I correctly achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your server code is written, if you receive a `/isprime` request and two child processes are already running, your request handler for `/isprime` does nothing.  It never sends any response.  You don't pass that first `if` test and then nothing happens afterwards.  So, that request will just sit there with the client waiting for a response.  Depending upon the client, it will probably eventually time out as a dead/inactive request and the client will shut it down.

Some clients (like browsers) may assume that something just got lost in the network and they may retry the request by sending it again.  It would be my guess that this is what is happening in your case.  The browser eventually times out and then resends the request.  By the time it retries, there are less than two child processes running so it gets processed on the retry.

You could verify that the browser is retrying automatically by going to the network tab in the Chrome debugger and watching exactly what the browser sends to your server and watch that third request, see it timeout and see if it is the browser retrying the request.

---

Note, this code seems to be only partially implemented because you initially start two child processes, but you don't reuse those child processes.  Once they finish and you decrement `maxChildrenRuning`, your code will then start another child process.  Probably what you really want to do is to keep track of the two child processes you started and when one finishes, add it to an array of "available child processes" so when a new request comes in, you can just use an existing child process that is already started, but idle.

You also need to either queue incoming requests when all the child processes are full or you need to send some sort of error response to the http request.  Never sending an http response to an incoming request is a poor design that just leads to great inefficiencies (connections hanging around much longer than needed that never actually accomplish anything).

Comment: Thank you for answer, I'll try to implement requests queue, childen processes idling also seem to be a reasonable approach.